# How to insert a row with a timestamp of "X days ago"

Tags: mysql

I am writing some code to generate dummy data for testing porpoises.

I would like a timestamp field to be within the last 90 days. Given that I have random 0 < X < 90, how do I `INSERT INTO table timestamp values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - X DAYS)`?  (ignoring the other fields, as I have no porblem with those)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), returns a random floating-point value `v` in the range `0 <= v < 1.0`. Use `ABS()` to get rid of floating values.

```
ABS(RAND() * 100)

INSERT INTO table (timestamp) values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL ABS(RAND() * 100) DAY)
```

SqlFiddle Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c51e/1)